# is it worth aligning variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been reading articles on the benefits of aligning variables. For example in C/C++, variables on the stack can be aligned using  `__attribute__( ( aligned ( .. ) ) )` and heap memory can be aligned using `std::align`.
If memory alignment is so important why don't all compilers do it automatically by default? At least I would have expected a gcc/g++ compiler flag for automatically aligning everything. However that does not appear to be the case and people still manually specify that memory should be aligned using the above mentioned ways. Why is that? Is it worth using the above ways of aligning memory or are there drawbacks? I would expect when using the -O2, -O3 flags a lot of memory alignment takes place as a way of optimizing a program. Thanks.

Comment: ***why don't all compilers do it automatically by default?*** One reason is it will waste memory.

Comment: The only situation where you need to worry about alignment is when you find yourself in a unique situation where every nanosecond counts, because if you don't take advantage of every available quantum of time, some other trader will and you will lose trillions of dollar. Of course, another way to avoid dealing with this insanity is simply avoiding this whole situation, and find yourself a job where modern computing hardware is perfectly adequate without requiring one to lose every last bit of sanity trying to hunt down every possible optimization, and you don't need to worry about alignment...

Comment: What reason do you have to think that compilers don't do it automatically by default? I would expect that the majority do. Though for some niche purposes developers might want to have greater control over the alignment, in general you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Actually, it's quite the contrary. Compilers do align variables properly. But, in almost all cases, it is not really needed. Current popular architectures can do unaligned access almost as fast as aligned access 99.9% of the time. So, aligning is a waste of memory. And maybe, if compilers didn't do alignment, cache will be utilized better, and your program would run faster.

Comment: For whoever decides to follow @SamVarshavchik's advice, don't bother chasing a job in AAA game development studios either. Or in any industry where real-time computing matters. It is so sad that programming came to this point of nonsensical disregard for performance such that questions are mocked at when they have a perfectly valid doubt about a **deeply relevant** performance concern.

Comment: Although it is true, @blipblop, that game development is very, very similar in this regard, real time trading is worse. With insane power of modern hardware, it's not necessary to squeeze out every last nanosecond in order to get realistic games. But in realtime trading every nanosecond is cash; but it's true: there are plenty of stories to be found in Slashdot archives about the horrible sweatshop-like game development coding environments. Not sure which one's more insane in total: game development, or trading. Fortunately, it does not matter. Avoiding either hell is much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

All compilers *do* alignment by default. It's just that there are some situations where you desire a *non-default* alignment.

The default alignment of a fundamental type is it's size. The default alignment of a class type is the maximum alignment of all it's bases and data members.

Many implementations support (as a language extension) an attribute `[[packed]]`, which *reduces* the alignment of a type to 1, eliminating padding between data members in class types. Such values are generally sent and received as a `char[]`, compared with `memcmp`, etc.

Other times you may wish to *increase* the alignment of some particular values, e.g. as [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735736/2610810) details

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you are doing. If you are doing heavy math with vectors or arrays you benefit strongly if you use custom alignment. For example with `avx-512` when you align your data with 64 bytes, you can directly load your data in blocks of 8 doubles into the `zmmm` registers via `_mm512_load_pd` apply `SIMD` instructions on it and store it back via `_mm512_stream_pd`.
Otherwise if you don't do heavy vectorized calculations you would simply waste memory, as pointed out by [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731279/is-it-worth-aligning-variables#comment92387660_52731279).

Further note that since C++11 you can use the [`alignas` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), e.g. you can define an aligned array as:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t Alignment = 64>
struct alignas(Alignment) AlignedArray : std::array<T, N> {};
```

And since C++17 you can use [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) for dynamic aligned allocations.

Comment: And there are also instructions which load packed values from the unaligned memory location, e.g. `_mm256_loadu_pd`. In my experience, their performance is not so bad compared with `_mm256_load_pd`.